# Ruby how to return index of a pair

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math, indexing

Today I got a task with given array and 'target' which is a sum of 2 integers within that list. After some time I came out with draft solution but it does not seem to be passing all of the tests. Algorithm seems to be considering integer at [0] twice.

```
def two_sum(numbers, target)

numbers.combination 2 do |a, b|
 if a + b == target
  return numbers.index(a), numbers.index(b)
  end
 end
end

print two_sum([1, 2, 3], 4) # Expected [0, 2] *OK

print two_sum([1234, 5678, 9012], 14690) # Expected [1, 2] *OK

print two_sum([2, 2, 3], 4) # Expected [0, 1]) but I get [0, 0]
```

I have tried to use .map first instead of .combination(2) method but with the exact same result :-/

Comment: Hint: What is `[2,2,3].index(2)`? And you need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code and watch what it is doing.

Comment: Use the index for the combination

Comment: Thanks guys. 'you need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code and watch what it is doing' - noted

Comment: @Krzynek : Since the question is already answered and accepted and tagged with the algorithm, you would have already moved on to the next problem, and that's fine. But looking at your 3 tests, `numbers` seems a sorted list. Which means you can reduce the time-complexity of your code if you look just close enough with a different approach. Maybe do that exercise when you get some time. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def two_sum(numbers, target)
  [*0..numbers.size-1].combination(2).find { |i,j| numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target }
end

two_sum([1234, 5678, 9012], 14690)
  #=> [1, 2]
two_sum([1234, 5678, 9012], 14691)
  #=> nil
```

Here is a more efficient method that may prove useful when the arrays are large.

```
require 'set'

def two_sum(arr, target)
  if target.even?
    half = target/2
    first = arr.index(half)
    if first
      last = arr.rindex(half)
      return [first, last] unless last.nil? || first == last
    end
  end
  a1, a2 = arr.uniq.partition { |n| n <= target/2 }
  s = a2.to_set
  n = a1.find { |n| s.include?(target-n) }
  n.nil? ? nil : [arr.index(n), arr.index(target-n)]
end
```

If `target` is even I first check to see if one-half of it appears at least twice in `arr`. If so, we are finished (except for determining and returning the associated indices). Even if the method does not terminate after this step it is required this step does not result in an early termination it is required before the next steps are performed.

If `target` is odd or is even but one-half of it appears less than twice in `arr` I construct a temporary array that contains unique values in `arr` and then partition that into two arrays, `a1`, containing values no greater than `target/2` and `a2`, containing values greater than `target/2`. It follows that if two numbers sum to `target` one must be in `a1` and the other must be in `a2`.

To speed calculations I then convert `a2` to a set `s`, and then loop through `a1` looking for a value `n` such that `s` contains `target-n`. Let's try it.

```
arr = 100_000.times.map { rand(1_000_000) }

puts "target      i1  arr[i1]     i2  arr[i2]  calc time (secs)"
puts "---------------------------------------------------------"

1000.times do
  t = Time.now
  target = rand(1_000_000)
  i1, i2 = two_sum(arr, target)
  print "#{target} -> "
  print i1.nil? ? "nil                        " :
    "#{i1}  #{arr[i1]}   #{i2}  #{arr[i2]}"
  puts "      #{(Time.now-t).round(4)} secs"
end
```

prints

```
target      i1  arr[i1]     i2  arr[i2]  calc time (secs)
---------------------------------------------------------
215113 ->   41   90943   11198  124170      0.027
344479 ->    0   78758   63570  265721      0.0237
188352 ->  190   79209   39912  109143      0.0275
   457 ->  nil                              0.0255
923135 ->   78   84600   43928  838535      0.0207
 59391 ->    2    5779    5454   53612      0.0289
259142 ->   73   58864   29278  200278      0.0284
364486 -> 8049  182243   89704  182243      0.001
895164 ->   13  205843    7705  689321      0.0228
880575 ->   20  440073    6195  440502      0.021
```

We see that `arr` does not contain two numbers that sum to `457`. Also, notice the very short time in the antepenultimate row. That's because one-helf of `target` (`364486/2 #=> 182243`) appears at least twice in `arr`.

Comment: What a nice place not to use an exclusive range :)

Comment: Magic! Now is time to go back to ruby-docs to make sure I completely understand this bit " [*0..numbers.size-1] "

Comment: `[*0..numbers.size-1]` can alternatively be written `(0..numbers.size-1).to_a`.

Comment: Krzynek, I modified my answer.